# How to use AJAX to send data to PHP, then use that data in further processing on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

Here's my setup:

I use javascript to get the width and height of the client. Then I pass these values to PHP and store them in $_SESSION. Then, in the further processing of the page *as it loads*, I need to access these session variables.

The problem: Due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX and PHP, this session variable is not accessible until after I reload the page.

Can I somehow get hold of these variables in PHP *on the first load*? Or is my only option to generate content based on further AJAX calls? Since it's only a single microscopic script, I'd be happy to halt execution of the page until the server has stored the session variable.

Note: I do not want to reload the page or have an alternate redirecting landing page.

Comment: use `AJAX`on first load or What I would do is saving data in cookies..

Comment: Return your stored session data in PHP and use it in `success` function of `ajax`.

Comment: I'm afraid that due to the nature of client-server interaction there's no other way but to have the page loaded for the first time *without* having this info in the PHP backend. I wonder though why you would need this kind of info in PHP in the first place.

Comment: store them in cookies on the first time, then load them every time page load.

Comment: For those of you who propose cookies, this approach doesn't work. As the page is rendered, the storage of the cookies doesn't happen until after PHP has done its work, or, we can't rely on the order of events to happen in any particular order. That's why I asked the question, to find out if anyone else have encountered (and solved) this challenge. But as far as I can see, it seems I must do my work in a separate AJAX event. I need to do it this way because the customer wants to load content from folders based on the screen size.